# eslint "Definition for rule 'no-explicit-any' was not found" always shown

Tags: typescript, eslint

Started a react/typescript project with `react-scripts`, added a `.eslintrc.json` file with the following content:

```json
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es2021": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:react/recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
        "react-app",
        "react-app/jest"
    ],
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        },
        "ecmaVersion": 12,
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "react",
        "@typescript-eslint"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "import/no-anonymous-default-export": "off",
        "no-explicit-any": "error",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-extra-semi": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": "error",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types": "error",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-inferrable-types": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-empty-interface": "off"
    }
}
```

Now, for some reason unknown to me, **every** file starts with the warning/error: `Line 1:1:  Definition for rule 'no-explicit-any' was not found  no-explicit-any`, even if the file doesn't even have the `any` type, and even if the file is empty!

It's an important rule, and I don't want to just ignore it.

Is it a bug? Am I doing something wrong?

Example of an almost-empty-file with this error:
[image: Example of an empty file]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try removing `"no-explicit-any": "error"` as this is not a valid eslint rule and this is where the error is thrown.

You have the rule enabled via `"@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": "error",`

Comment: Forgot removing that one, it was part of my eslint research. Thx!